# How to determine the family of bounded functions from an infinite Fort space to $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition:** Let $X$ be a topological space and $b\in X$. We call $X$ a **Fort space** (with particular point $b$), when $X$ has topology $\{A\subseteq X: b \not\in A \; \text{or} \; X\setminus A\; \text{is finite}\} $.

It is clear that a Fort space $X$ with particular point $b$, $X\setminus b$ is discrete and $X$ is one-point compactification of $X\setminus b$. So, a Fort space is simply ''Alexandroff Compactification of a Discrete Space''.

Now, let $X$ be an infinite Fort space with particular point $b$. I want to determine the family of all bounded functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$.

Actually, I don't know where to start and what to search for... So, any help is definitely appreciated.

Comment: Isn't each function to $[0,1]$ bounded?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think it's different. By a bounded function we mean a function that the set of its values is bounded. Equivalently, if we can find a $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$. For instance, if we set $f(x)=x^2$, $f(x)$ is not bounded itself, but if we define $f(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ it would be bounded! I need functions that are bounded themselves...

Comment: So you want to determine all bounded functions $f : X \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Somehow yes! But not exactly! I want all functions such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ and $M \in [0,1]$...

Comment: And you only consider *continuous* functions? Otherwise the topology on $X$ would be irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yeah! Actually I've got to find $\mathcal{F}$:=the family of bounded functions, $\mathcal{F}_1$:=family of continuous functions, and $\mathcal{F}_0$:=family of upper semi-continuous functions and then prove that $\mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Okay, you ask for a proof that $\mathcal F_1 \subset \mathcal F_0 \subset \mathcal F$. This is a completely different question. In the present form your question does not make much sense. I recommend that you edit your question.

Comment: The functions in $\mathcal F$ are not required to have any other property than being bounded, so there is *no other way* to describe them.

Comment: Proving that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_1$ is the 4th step of answering my question. For the first 3 steps I have to determine what are the families like! You are right about $\mathcal{F}$. Do you have any ideas about $\mathcal{F}_1$? I think there might be some problems on the special point $b$ of $X$...

Answer (score 1):

The question is only interesting when $X$ is infinite (if $X$ is finite, then it is discrete and all functions are continuous and bounded).

Clearly $\mathcal F_1 \subset \mathcal F_0$. This is true for **all** spaces $X$. What about $\mathcal F_0 \subset \mathcal F$?

Let us write $X = D \cup \{ \infty \}$ where $D$ is a discrete space. $D$ is open in $X$. Obviuosly each function $f : X  \to \mathbb R$ is continuous in all $x \in D$. Hence $f$ is (upper, lower semi-) continuous if and only $f$ is (upper, lower semi-) continuous at the point $\infty$.

The following are equivalent:

(1) $f$ is upper semi-continuous.

(2) For each $\varepsilon > 0$ the set $S^+_\varepsilon  = \{x \in D \mid f(x) \ge f(\infty) + \varepsilon \}$ is finite.

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): There exist an open neigborhood $U$ of $\infty$ such $f(x) < f(\infty) + \varepsilon$ for all $x \in U$. Since $X \setminus U$ is finite, we are done.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1): $U = X \setminus S^+_\varepsilon$ is an open neighborhood of $\infty$. For $x \in U$ we obviously have $f(x) < f(\infty) + \varepsilon$. Hence $f$ is upper semi-continuous at $\infty$.

(1) shows that each upper semi-continuous function $f$ has an upper bound. However, it does not necessarily have a lower bound. As an example let $X$ be the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb N$ and define $f : X \to \mathbb R, f(n) = -n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f(\infty) = 0$.

This shows that $\mathcal F_0 \subset \mathcal F$ is not true.

Similarly, each lower semi-continuous function $f$ has a lower bound, but not necessarily an upper bound.

We conclude that each continuous function is bounded. This is fairly trivial because $X$ is compact which implies that $f(X)$ is a compact subset of  $\mathbb R$. Hence $\mathcal F_1 \subset \mathcal F$.

The functions in $\mathcal F_1$ are characterized by the property that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ the set $S_\varepsilon  = \{x \in D \mid \lvert f(x) - f(\infty)\rvert \ge \varepsilon \}$ is finite.

Comment: Is it possible to find a function from $X$ to $[0 , 1]$ which is not bounded??? As the definition of bounded function says we can find $2\in \mathbb{R}$ which for every function f from $X$ to $[0 ,1]$ that satisfies $|f(x)| \leq 2$. So it is not possible to find a function which is not bounded but it's semi-continuous...

Comment: No, each function to $[0,1]$ (which is a *bounded* interval) is of course bounded. Each semi-continuous function has an upper or a lower bound (see my answer).